# chart in windows form application with different starting position at x axis

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I want to create a chart in windows form application in visual studio with c#.

I have these values:

```
int []x={10,20,30,20,15,16,20,32,40,40,50,12,15,20,30} 
int[] y={10,20,30,45,20,20}
```

and I want to create a chart where the x table has the X axis from 1 to 15, and the Y from 6 to 11 at the same axis. I know how to put two different table at a chart but how do I make the second one displaced in x axis?

My code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    this.chart2.Series["first value"].Points.AddXY(i, x[i]);
for (int i = 6; i < y.Length; i++)
    this.chart2.Series["second value"].Points.AddXY(i, y[i]);
```

And I see only my first x values. Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post an image of what you want it to look like? I'm not quite sure from your question...

Comment: @mmathis http://postimg.org/image/ec5p3x1nf/. yeah sorry i couldn;t say it any better in english, i want my second diagram to be like the blue line in the middle of the graph

Comment: ok i found it i put it like this and it was ok   for (int i = 6; i < 6+y.Length; i++)
                    this.chart2.Series["second value"].Points.AddXY(i, y[i-6]);